# What's wrong with my List Comprehension?

Tags: python

How come this runs

```
[int(x, 16) for x in ['BB', 'A7', 'F6', '9E']]
```

But this doesn't?

```
mylist = ['BB','A7','F6','9E']
mylist2 = [int(x, 16) for x in [mylist]]
```

Am I missing something fundamental here?

Comment: `[mylist]` is `[['BB','A7','F6','9E']]`…

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`[mylist]` is a list of only 1 element: `mylist`.

On the first iteration, `x` will become the entire `mylist`, then you basically have:

```
int(mylist, 16)
```

Which doesn't make a lot of sense.

Don't wrap it in an extra list if you want to iterate over `mylist`:

```
[int(x, 16) for x in mylist]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mylist = ['BB','A7','F6','9E']
mylist2 = [int(x, 16) for x in mylist]
```

Should work